# issues with incorporating sub model which includes iterating featureclasses as output

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, feature-class, parameters, iterator

Does anyone know why my model builder does not work when I tried to incorporate a sub-model into my main model?

This is my problem:

I created a sub model in which copies featureclasses within a folder to another folder. I used the iterator featureclass to copy all of it and used $name% as my output name for each feature classes. I've set the input workspace and output it as my model parameters.

I then added the sub model into my main model which shows up with model parameters. It is connected to my merge process as the input.

I ran the model as a whole and it gave me error 000229: Cannot open ...\%Name%.shp warning. Failed to execute (Merge ALL feature classes in processing Folder)

This seems like the issue in which ArcGIS can not locate my featureclasses as it seems to interpret %name% as a shapefile name when it is the output from iterators?

Answer (score 2):

Your sub-model should end with a Collects Value tool (exposed as a parameter). This collects the featureclasses and returns a *list* to the master model. Your merge tool can take this *list* as the input.